# Using the phrase break a leg

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Which of the following is a correct usage of the phrase `break a leg`:
`Break a leg in the presentation` or `Break a leg for the presentation`
If I think of `Break a leg` = `Good luck` it seems that 2nd one is correct because one is wishing good luck for the presentation; good luck in the presentation is probably wrong grammatically. Is that correct?
or when we are using phrases or idioms the usual rules of grammar are not applied as an idiom or a phrase could be used in various different ways?

Answer (score 3):

*Break a leg* ≠ *good luck*

It's true that the meaning of *break a leg* is more or less *good luck*; however, they are not equivalent, in the sense that you can't replace one with the other.

These examples do ***not*** work:

- I always have *break a leg*
- I wish you *break a leg*
- May we have *break a leg*
- Finding a four-leaf clover brings *break a leg*

This is to say, trying to figure out how to use the expression *break a leg* based on how we use the expression *good luck* is not going to work. If you wanted to try to apply general grammar rules in order to extend the use of *break a leg*, you'd be better off thinking about how *break a leg* would function in a literal (not the idiom) way:

*I hope that you will break your leg for the presentation* - this would mean something like *I hope that in preparation for the presentation you break your leg*

*I hope that you will break your leg in the presentation* - this would mean something like *I hope that during the presentation, you break your leg*.

Either one of these would work grammatically and semantically.

### *BUT*

You probably shouldn't do this.  It is always risky to attempt to extend idioms.  Idioms are often not understood literally, and if you try to modify them to fit into some other context, the result may sound confusing, or just unnatural.

In this case, the safest option is to stick with the idiomatic usage:

I heard you have to give a presentation tomorrow.  Break a leg!

Comment: I hope that you will break your leg for the presentation - this would mean something like I hope that in preparation for the presentation you break your leg

I hope that you will break your leg in the presentation - this would mean something like I hope that during the presentation, you break your leg.   `So in both these sentences the usage is wrong?`

Answer (score 2):

This comes from the theatre.  Actors are superstitious people, and if someone wishes them "I hope you have good luck!" (or, abbreviated "Good luck!")  they believe it will make something go wrong with the play.

So instead of saying that, you say "I hope you break your leg!"  Because if you wish for the worst - then the best must happen (!?).  You can shorten this to an imperative "Break a leg."  You wouldn't combine it with any other words, it is a complete sentence.

It doesn't really work as an expression except in the theatre, but I suppose a presentation is like a performance, so someone might use it there.  If you're not superstitious then just "Good luck" is fine and is probably more common, even before a play.

Comment: I know an actor. If I said to him 'Good luck in _Macbeth_ tomorrow night!', he'd have two reasons to never speak to me again.

Comment: I'm not superstitious at all - touch wood - but the last time someone said 'Break a leg' before a performance, my co-star fell over a cameraman's cable mid-performance  & nearly did. [Long time ago, of course, cameras don't have cables these days]